# Why does a firewall allow this? Network address less than host min

Tags: ip, firewall, subnet

I have a firewall setup to allow traffic from network 192.168.1.192/29. Traffic from 192.168.1.192 is allowed through, however, using one of the online network calculators I noticed that the network's min host is 192.168.1.193... Why is the firewall allowing this traffic to pass?

Thanks.

Comment: The `.192` address is the network address. If you want an answer, you need to edit your question to include the firewall model, configuration, and what you have that shows the problem.

Comment: Well my Cisco ASA is even picking it up in the encryption domain, with 192.168.1.192/29 meant to be my side of the encryption domain... why is 192.168.1.192/32 considered to be inside the encryption domain? The firewall is up in Google's cloud - the rule is set to allow sources from network 192.168.1.192/29, but I can connect from IP 192.168.1.192, when apparently the min host in that subnet is 192.168.1.193... Is this normal?

Comment: What you fail to understand is that the addresses that can be assigned to hosts in a network start with `network+1` but you are allowing _all_ addresses starting with the network and extending through the broadcast address. Any address from `192.168.1.192` to `192.168.1.199` is covered by `192.168.1.192/29`. What a router allows is not subject to what addresses can be assigned to a host in a network.

Comment: @RonMaupin you should covert that comment to an answer, so that OP can accept. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you fail to understand is that the addresses that can be assigned to hosts in a network start with `network+1` but you are allowing all addresses starting with the `network` and extending through the `broadcast address`. Any address from `192.168.1.192` to `192.168.1.199` is covered by `192.168.1.192/29`. What a router allows is not subject to what addresses can be assigned to a host in a network.